# When exactly do you need to import in PHP?

Tags: php, class, import, autoload

When autoloading classes, the following runs without a problem:

```
<?php

namespace App\Resources;

class Home extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        echo 'home/index';

    }
}
```

How does this work? I never imported the `Controller` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Resources;

use App\Resources\Controller;

class Home extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        echo 'home/index';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use non-qualified class name (without the namespace), PHP assumes you mean the current namespace. The code above works because both Home and Controller are in the same namespace **App\Resources**.